# SetInterval($.get Pool of 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, pool

To avoid multi requests on my server I am trying to implement a pool: So I do a request every 30sec that send me data once if it found it, or if 30 sec have passed.

```
//getchat.php

$pool=0;
$chatmsg= array();

while($pool<30 && count($chatmsg)==0){

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id > ".addslashes($_GET['id'])." ORDER BY id ASC");
    $i=0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $chatmsg[$i]=array("message"=>htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlentities($row["message"])));
        $i++;
    }

    sleep(1);
    $pool++;
}

echo json_encode($chatmsg);
flush();
```

```
//script.js

setInterval(function() {
    $.get("getchat.php", {
        id: chatid
    }, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

}, 30000);
```

But the messages shows after 30 secondes! What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I finally found:

```js
function getchat(){ 
$.get("getchat.php", {
        id: chatid
    }, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
         getchat();
    });

}
```

Comment: What happens if you call "getchat.php?id=someid" from browser? Does it actually return any json?

Comment: Yes it does! I have all the json

Comment: Perhaps you should consider web sockets instead of using `sleep()` like that in your server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

The message shows after 30 seconds because you have an interval. It's being called only after 30 seconds. If you want to call it instantly you can change the code like so:

```
//script.js

function getChat() {
    $.get("getchat.php", {
        id: chatid
    }, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
getChat();
setInterval(getChat, 30000);
```

**EDIT**

I've made my own test to recreate the situation:

```
// index.php
while (!file_exists(__DIR__ . '/flag')) {
    sleep(1);
}

echo date('r');
flush();
die;


// index.html

<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function getChat() {
     $.get(
         "index.php", 
         {}, 
         function(data) {
             console.log(data);
         }
     );
}
getChat();
setInterval(getChat, 10000);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

And whenever I call index.html, I can see a pending request in the console. After I create file "flag" it is instantly stopped and I get a date in the console.log.

I could suggest you to 2 things:

1. Recheck console for pending requests. They should be running there.
2. Recreate more simple situation in your php code without DB involved.

Comment: Yes I already have this, but after when I send a new message it doesn't show instantly

Comment: So why would it show instantly? You only call for an update every 30 seconds. If you have sleeps on php side, you might also change setInterval time to 1 second. But that will break your server at some point

Comment: because it should show the request of the last setInterval request that is pending